# cordova google-analytics-plugin plugin not tracking data in GA

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I followed this tutorial to setup the plugin in my app: http://blog.nraboy.com/2014/06/using-google-analytics-ionicframework/, however my GA doesn't show any tracking data at all. I use following method to test it, it runs with any error and out put the correct success message as well. any idea?

Thanks

```
 analytics.trackView(state, function(success){
 console.log("** tracking success");
  console.log(success);
  }, function(error){
console.log("** tracking error");
console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me when i replaced

```
analytics.trackView('Home');
```

with

```
window.analytics.trackView('Home');
```

Checkout implementation on http://shashibadhuk.com/phonegap/implement-google-analytics-on-phonegap-mobile-app/